# "На хрен": возможно ли слитное написание — "нахрен"?

Tags: семантика, предлоги, слитно-раздельно, наречия, существительные

Скажите, верно ли, что нет наречия "нахрен", но существует наречное выражение (или предлог плюс существительное) "на хрен"? Или всё же есть? "Грамота.ру" говорит, что те же "на хрена" и "до хрена" пишутся раздельно (см. [Грамоту.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=271139)). В "Нацкорпусе" же почему-то довольно много примеров со слитным написанием: и "нахрена", и "нахрен" (см. [Нацкорпус](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&ct=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD)); это ошибки, что ли, или язык стал допускать такие варианты? Какова вообще текущая ситуация в русском языке с этим "на хрен" с точки зрения правил?

*Меня на хрен задолбала эта работа.*

(Теоретически тут "на хрен" = "очень сильно, невыносимо, донельзя", поэтому просится слитное написание, но допустимо ли это? Судя по "Нацкорпусу", вполне...)

*Пошлю его на хрен.*

(Теоретически тут уже значение: "Куда?" — "На хрен", "К чёрту", поэтому явно предлог с существительным?)

**ДОПОЛНЕНО**

"Грамота.ру" в итоге ответила, что "на хрен" нужно писать РАЗДЕЛЬНО из-за словарной фиксации (см. [Грамоту.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer/?s=309658)).

Comment: Спасибо за информацию. Ну и кто вам больше помог разобраться в теме: Грамота.ру или наш форум?  Про правило и про  словарную фиксацию я тоже говорила, но при этом дала дополнительный материал о современной практике письма.

Comment: Пока есть фиксированная норма, буду следовать ей (раздельное написание), однако, конечно, понимаю, что язык развивается, в "Нацкорпус" и просто книги проникают и другие варианты, которые можно оправдать (слитное написание). В этом смысле ваш ответ, разумеется, больше помог разобраться. Благодарю:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Раздельное написание предлога НА свидетельствует о наличии **падежного управления**.

Наречные выражения (или обстоятельственные существительные) могут употребляться в различных падежах, но наиболее часто используется В.п., имеющий **направленное значение.**

Кроме обычной **пространственной ориентации**, существуют и другие:

– оценка с ориентацией на чувства, ощущения: *на зависть, на вкус*

–  результат, следствие: *на износ,  на славу*

– цель: *подарить на память*; также с предлогом В: в заключение, *в придачу, в насмешку*.

2. В словаре русского **арго**  фиксируются только раздельные формы письма: ***на хрен, на хрена*** http://gramota.ru/slovari/argo/?page=32&alpha=%CD

Однако практика активно воздействует на словарный выбор, и в Нацкорпусе, в том числе в художественных произведениях, слитное написание ***нахрен, нахрена*** встречается достаточно часто.

3. В этом случае пользователи пока еще видят падежное управление только в пространственных выражениях (***иди на хрен***), в других же  явно преобладает чисто наречный смысл.

Более того, иногда такое наречие приобретает значение **вводности** и обособляется, выражая различные негативные оценки и эмоции.

4. Поэтому часть пользователей еще ориентируются **на правила**, в то время как остальные считают слитное написание этих наречий более обоснованным.

**Примеры из Нацкорпуса.**

― А мне теперь ― разбирайся? Да **нахрена** мне это надо?! Ты что ― не мог сказать? [Анатолий Мельник. Авторитет (2000)]

«Да ну **нахрен**», ― сказал Петров, стряхивая с себя этот морок. [А. Б. Сальников. Петровы в гриппе и вокруг него // «Волга», 2016]

― Какие, **нахрен**, старшие товарищи, ― протянул Сергей Сергеевич с недоверием. [А. Б. Сальников. Отдел // «Волга», 2015]

Кого я **нахрен** от кого защищал или защищаю?! [Я. Г. Солонин. Шум. Бумага. Грецкие орехи. Безразличие // «Волга», 2014]